# Как сделать скидку по времени для Woocommerce категорий?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть такой сниппет для functions.php

```
function get_discount_period_rate(){
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');
    $rate = 0.65; // 35% скидка 

    $start_time = mktime( 11, 00, 00, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y") );
    $end_time   = mktime( 22, 59, 59, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y") );
    $time_now   = strtotime("now");
    return $start_time <= $time_now && $end_time > $time_now ? $rate : false;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'periodic_discount_prices', 99, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'periodic_discount_prices', 99, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_prices_sale_price', 'periodic_discount_prices', 99, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'periodic_discount_prices', 99, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'periodic_discount_prices', 99, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'periodic_discount_prices', 99, 3 );
function periodic_discount_prices( $price, $product, $parent = 0 ){
    $discounted_products = array( 8710 );
    if( get_discount_period_rate() && in_array( $product->get_id(), $discounted_products ) ){
        $price = $product->get_regular_price() * get_discount_period_rate();
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Он настроен так, что бы товары указанные в переменной discounted_products получали скидку по времени.
Как переделать код, что бы я мог указать категории товаров?

Comment: Еще одна проблема образовалась с этим снипетом, скидки показывает только авторизированным админам!
Как это исправить?

Comment: Нашел оригинал вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024563/discount-on-specific-products-based-on-a-daily-time-range-in-woocommerce
Но автор не отвечает